# Resize image to browser width/height without cropping

Tags: css, fullscreen

How could I got about setting the size of an img to 100% width/height while not cropping? I've found many that use body background, but also crop the image. I just want to make it 100% width/or height (whichever comes first) thus not cropping the remaining width or height. Does that make sense?

EDIT************

I figured it out using the background method

```
<?php
$i = $_GET['i'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

html {
        background: url("<?php echo $i; ?>") no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
        -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
        -o-background-size: auto 100%;
        background-size: auto 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want it to resize so the image is stretched as much as possible, but it retains its original aspect ratio and is not cropped?

Comment: Exactly. I am embedding a web view in android and in landscape mode, the squarish image needs to be stretched as big as possible without cropping. The current method I am using is making it as big as possible, but it is also cropping the image which I do not want

Comment: I figured it out. Using a css3 property worked. Android uses web kit I believe so that should be fine

Answer (score -1):

The following CSS will do this for you

```
position: fixed;      
left: 0px;
top: 0px;    
width:100% ;     
height:100% ;
```

Comment: That does not retain aspect ratio

Comment: "How could I got about setting the size of an img to 100% width/height while not cropping? "  You do not say anything about maintaining aspect ratio ... you are starting to remind me of a project manager...

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear I guess. @sdleihssirhc figured it out

Comment: really? You vote that down? You would think the part in my description saying "I've found many that use body background, but also crop the image." would be enough information to let you know that it is supposed to maintain aspect ratio. If it wasn't cropping it would obviously not maintain aspect ratio

Comment: I can have it not crop and not maintain aspect ratio... I kind of think that your solution does crop on some screens.  And you said you wanted to show an image not that you wanted to set a back ground.

Comment: yeah I suppose it crops on width. You can see what I was trying to achieve here: http://dopserv1.dop.com/mv/image.php?i=http://presentationism.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/wrong-slide2.JPG ...What I have now is working for me

Comment: I get what you were trying to achieve now... but that is not the solution you asked for.  Just like a project manager

Comment: You're right...it is halfway to the solution I asked for. It is still cropping on width which I would love to get rid of. Enlighten us on how to do it coder.

Comment: I would get 2 images one for landscape orientation and one for normal and sqap them out on flip. You are not going to be able to avoid a crop on one or the other of your aspects and maintain the ratio...